# Preferences Support Library - SwitchPreference not working

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, android-switch

A few days ago Google introduced the `Preference Support Library` ([Link](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T)). I've just tried to implement it in my application though it seems like it's not working with `SwitchPreferences` which is weird because Google states that we can use the same XML-Files as before and explicity says that SwitchPreferences are now available to all API 7+ devices.

Quote ([Source](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T))

> [...] and add preferences using the same preference XML files
>   (http://goo.gl/wOcIxI), while adding support for elements such as
>   SwitchPreference (previously only available on API 14+ devices) to all
>   API 7+ devices. [...]

**Error message**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class (not found)SwitchPreference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Relevant part is obviously `Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class (not found)SwitchPreference`.

**Java code**

```
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pref_something"
        android:summary="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:title="Lorem ipsum" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

So basically the question is: Am I doing something wrong or is this indeed a bug of the Preference Support Library?

Comment: what is the android version of the device you are testing with?

Comment: @DerekFung 22 (5.1.1)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`SwitchPreference` added in API level 14. if you are using Preferences Support Library v7, you must use `SwitchPreferenceCompat` instead.

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    android:key="pref_something"
    android:summary="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    android:title="Lorem ipsum" />
```

Comment: That's it. I've thought about something like this already unfortunately I couldn't find anything - docs suck sometimes. Google should really mention [SwitchCompatPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SwitchPreferenceCompat.html) on the [SwitchPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) page.